# Using Replicate Weights to Determine Direct Standard Error for PUMS Data

Tags: r, excel, standard-error, census

I am working with 2010-2014 5-year PUMS data. I am trying to use the replicate weights to find the standard error. The standard error formula is in the documentation, but I am having trouble turning this in to a formula in Microsoft Excel or R, the two programs I am working with. I can crosstab two variables in Excel to get the sum of each replicate weight and PWGTP, but I imagine there is a simpler way.

Has anyone here worked with PUMS data and the replicate weights? Documentation can be found here:

http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/pums/documentation.2014.html

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can do something like this:

```
wgt <- "PWGTP"
var <- "SEX"

est <- aggregate(PUMS[[wgt]], by=list(PUMS[[var]]), FUN=sum, simplify=T, drop=F)

err <- vector("list", 80)
for(i in 1:80){
  err[[i]] <- aggregate(PUMS[[paste0(wgt, i)]], by=list(PUMS[[var]]), FUN=sum, simplify=T, drop=F)
  err[[i]] <- (err[[i]][,2] - est[,2])**2
}

SE <- ((4/80)*colSums(do.call(rbind, err)))**.5
```

This is assuming that you are using the Person Record and computing the SE for the variable "SEX".

There are other formulas for computing the SE of a mean, median, proportion, etc. The formula used here is probably the most commonly used one, so I am assuming that this is the one you are inquiring about.

Answer (score 1):

The `survey` and `srvyr` packages will be useful to you.

```R
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)

hga <- read_csv("ss11hga.csv") # georgia, but it will be the same for you

# survey design, specifying replicate weights
pumsd_hh <- hga %>%
  as_survey_rep(
    weights = WGTP, 
    repweights = starts_with("WGTP"),
    combined_weights = TRUE
  )

# calculate average income and standard error by size of household
pumsd_hh %>%
  filter(!is.na(FINCP)) %>%
  mutate(NP = ifelse(NP > 5, 5, NP)) %>%
  group_by(NP) %>%
  summarise(
    survey_mean(FINCP, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```